# Can someone explain to me the output of the below mentioned python program?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the below-mentioned code, but could not understand the line `for i in b`

```
a = [1,2]
b = 1
c = [1,2,3,4]
    
def myIn(a,b):
    for i in b:     #what this line is doing here?
        if i==a:
            return(True)
    return(False)   

myIn(a,b)
```

Comment: I mean, if you would only write down in google you could easily understand what it does.

Comment: Depends on what 'b' parameter is on your example. If 'b' is an int, it's a syntax error. If 'b' is a list, it's a for loop just like the answer by @Goldwave.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp). It iterates through an iterable, like a list, in your example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the similar naming of variables got you confused.

myIn is a function that takes in 2 arguments a and b, where a is a variable (not a list) and b is a list.

The function loops through every element in list b and checks if an element in b is equal to variable a if so it returns True, else it returns False.

Answer (score 0):

Here, in loop `for i in b:`, `b` is an integer that is not iterable. You will face an error message like this `'int' object is not iterable`.

An iterable object must be a collection of elements. It could be a list, dictionary, set, etc.